# VB.net "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." when entering Visual Studio Debug

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

My boyfriend and I have spent the last 2 hours trying to get this to work, we have tried putting all the data connections into try's, changing the the connections to gloabal's but whatever we do we end up back at the same problem. The page will load fine when loaded via localhost, but when we try to get in via debug it hits this error.

If we put the code that fails into a try it goes through each connection and then will load, but each part will have been caught in the catch.

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Here's the code, each sub or function that uses MySQL connection has a close in the same as this function. We are out of ideas to what it causing it, as only does it we try and enter debug in Visual Studio.

```
    Public Function getID()

        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        Dim rtr As Integer

        cmd.CommandText = "MySQLSTATEMENT"
        cmd.Connection = CON_STRING

        Connection.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If (reader.HasRows()) Then
            reader.Read()
            rowID = reader.Item(0)
        End If

        Connection.Close()
        reader.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should Close reader first and then you can close the connection. 
I would recommend Using Statement for connection that will take care of closings the connection.

Comment: I'll try it with the using statement tomorrow, thanks